# The internal mechanism of GetMessage() in Win32 API?

Tags: windows

In the Message Loop of a windows application,the GetMessage() function will suspend the application thread when there is no message in the message queue, but how it manages to wake itself up when a message was enqueued into the  message queue? How can a sleeping thread wake itself up?

```
while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
         {
              TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
              DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They wait in the same manner as how a typical asynchronous wait thread waits (using `WaitForSingleObject`). Internally (in the kernel level), they all wait using a kernel API function called `KeWaitForSingleObject`

Answer (score 2):

The thread doesn't wake *itself* up. The thread that sends it the message wakes *it* up. Part of the process of sending a message includes waking the recipient of the message.

Comment: If I click a button on an applicaiton, can we say "the process of sending a message" is Windows itself?

Comment: It involves a large number of things, from the keyboard or mouse driver to the scheduler. In the typical case, all of those things are parts of Windows.